# foreach in formulário wordpress não funciona

Tags: wordpress

Estou fazendo um envio de email, usando a função nativa do wordpress `wp_mail` onde envio vários campos concatenados na variável `$message`, inclusive os checkbox marcados pelo usuário. Apesar de acreditar estar fazendo certo, esses checkbox são os únicos que apontam erros e não são enviados, aparecendo o erro:

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in functions.php line 92
```

onde esta linha tem o seguinte

```
foreach ( $_POST['salgados_selecionados'] as $key => $value ) {
   $message .= $value;
}
```

os checkbox são vários, mas um exemplo seria

```
<input type="checkbox" name="salgados_selecionados" id="232" value="Bolinha com carne seca">
<input type="checkbox" name="salgados_selecionados" id="258" value="Bolinha de queijo">
<input type="checkbox" name="salgados_selecionados" id="256" value="Coxinha">
```

Já usei essa mesma ideia em um outro projeto e funcionava.

Comment: O problema está em $_POST['salgados_selecionados'] De onde está vindo isso? um select ? um radio ? um text ? .    faça isso e mostre o que aparece : var_dump($_POST['salgados_selecionados'])

Comment: Editei a pergunta, são checkbox.
Quando faço o var_dump ele aparece somente o ultimo checkbox selecionado `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in functions.php on line 86 string(7) "Coxinha"`

Comment: alterei o name para salgados_selecionados[] e agora funcionou. Na primeira versão já estava assim, mas já mexi tanto nesse código que acabei arrumando sem nem saber o que tava errado a primeira vez.

Comment: O correto seria vc tratar este &_POST que vc está recebendo antes de enviar para um foreach, até pela segurança da sua aplicação.